# Who will win this series? Will it ever end?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In a unique hockey series between India and Pakistan, they decide to play on till a team wins 5 matches. The number of ways in which the series can be won by India, if no match ends in a draw is :

A) 126 (EDIT: earlier it was 125 due to typing error, so in answers question is critisied for that)

B) 252

C)225

D)none

I cannot figure out what to do. Its a question of permutation and combination.
The answer is A)126

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series cannot go on for more than $9$ games, since at that point one of the teams must have won $5$ games. It's convenient, mathematically, to imagine that the series continues, even after the winner has been determined, to a full $9$ games, with the winner simply forfeiting the unnecessary games, so that they wind up winning the series 5-4.  The number of different ways this can happen is

$${9\choose5}={9!\over5!4!}={9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\over4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}=126$$

Comment: @user251573, if you prefer, you can think of it this way: Label $5$ of the $9$ games scheduled as Wins for India, and label the others as either Losses or Left-unplayed. You still have $5$ Ws and $4$ Ls, which can occur in any of $9\choose5$ ways.

Answer (score 6):

So there can either be 5,6,7,8 or 9 games in the series (if it reaches 9 games, the result has to be 5-4).

5 games: India win every game - 1 combination

6 games: India win all but one - they must have lost 1 of the first 5 games - 5 combinations

7 games: India lose 2 of the first 6 games - ${6}\choose{2}$ combinations - 15 combinations

Continue like this and you should get the correct answer which is 126, not 125.

Comment: I was about to complain that the 7 games one must also match the rule of the 6 games one -- that one of the first five must be a loss -- but that is taken care of by the existing constraint on 7 and the pigeonhole principle.